# Copy all files from a directory without creating subdirectories

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

I am trying to take a directory and create a new directory in TEMP, that contains all the files in the original directory, but not create additional sub-directories.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath() + "C# Temporary Files"));
            string lastFolder = new DirectoryInfo(folders.SelectedPath).Name;

foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(folders.SelectedPath, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(s=>s.EndsWith(".c")|| s.EndsWith(".h")))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(folders.SelectedPath, Path.GetTempPath() + "C# Temporary Files\\" + GlobalVar.GlobalInt));
                }
```

This works in copying files that are in the directory itself, but not files in subdirectories.  Instead it throws the error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException.

An example of the error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Temp\C# Temporary Files\*outer
>   directory\sub-directory*\*filename*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd it recursively - maybe something like the below pseudo code... not tested..

```
public void CopyRecursive(string path, string newLocation)
{
    foreach(var file in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(path))
    {
        File.Copy(file.FullName, newLocation + file.Name);
    }

    foreach(var dir in DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        CopyRecursive(path + dir.Name, newLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was able to use this to get something working.